# connection must be valid and open c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new to C# but i'm developing a simple GUI to manage my mysql database.
I need to keep connection open until the end of the program (when I close it) but after clicking connection button, I insert some data but program shows "connection  must be valid and open". Could you help me?

```
namespace MysqlConn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static MySqlConnection conn;
        MySqlCommand mcd;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetConn();         
        }

        public static MySqlConnection GetConn()
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username='+UserName'; password= '+PassWord'");
            MessageBox.Show("OK..");
            return conn;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String DataBase = textBoxDb.Text;
            String UserName = textBoxUserName.Text;
            String PassWord = textBoxPassword.Text;

        }

        public void openCon()
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }  
        }

        public void closedConn()
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        public void executeQuery(String s)
        {
            try
            {

                mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, conn);
                if (mcd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Query executed");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Query not executed");
                }

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            } finally
            {

            }
        }

        private void buttonInsert_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "insert into prova_csharp.users (Name, Surname, Age) values ('"+textBoxName.Text+"', '"+textBoxSurname.Text+"', '"+textBoxAge.Text+"')";
            executeQuery(s);
        }

        private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "update prova_csharp.users set Name='" + textBoxName.Text + "', Surname='" + textBoxSurname.Text + "', Age=" + textBoxAge.Text + " where Id=" + textBoxId.Text;
            executeQuery(s);
        }

        private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "delete from prova_csharp.users where Id = " + textBoxId.Text;
            executeQuery(s);
            textBoxId.Text = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well the only place you're opening the connection is inside `openCon()` and that is never called.

Comment: The error seems fairly self explanatory.  I'd suggest the connection isn't open, as I don't see anywhere you actually call `openCon` or otherwise call `conn.Open`.

Comment: Also, please make sure you use parameterized queries. Those are classic sql injection, using user input (textbox) in inserts like that. And call Dispose on that connection when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calling GetConn(); on button click.

```
conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username='+UserName'; password= '+PassWord'");
    MessageBox.Show("OK..");
    return conn;
```

Making a new connection doesn't open it.
add the `conn.Open()` to the GetConn(); function, and then just `conn.Close()` when needed.

Comment: thanks friend, your help was fundamental!